# Login with CDI, @Produces returns cached value

Tags: java, jsf, scope, cdi, lifecycle

I'm trying to implement login mechanizm using CDI `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

Code:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Auth implements Serializable {

  private User user;

  @Inject
  private UserStore userStore;

  @Produces @CurrentUser
  public User getUser() {
    if (user == null) {
        Principal principal= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();

            if (principal != null) {

                Map parameters = new HashMap();
                parameters.put("email", principal.getName());

                user = (User) userStore.findWithNamedQuery(User.GET_BY_EMAIL, parameters).get(0);
            }
        }

        return user;
    }

    public void logout() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.invalidateSession();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/");
    }
}
```

The class that always receives the same `User` instance:

```
@Stateful
public class NewsService implements Serializable {

    @Inject @CurrentUser
    private User currentUser;

    @Inject
    private NewsStore newsStore;

    public List<News> getNewsForLoggedUser(Integer start, Integer limit) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user", currentUser);

        return (List<News>) newsStore.findWithNamedQuery(News.getAllForUser, params, start, limit);
    }
}
```

There problem is with `getUser()` method. Even though the session was invalidated it still returns value from the first login. How can I destroy CDI bean or change it so it outputs always actual value? I tried annotation `logout()` method with `@PreDestroy`, but it produces such error:

```
13:20:50,329 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (default task-22) WELD-000019 Error destroying an instance Managed Bean [class com.intenso.presentation.Auth] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named] of com.intenso.presentation.Auth@59821e
```

I'm running on WildFly 8.0.0.Alpha4

Comment: The error indicates that the bean is in fact in dependent scope, see the `@Default` part of it? Are you sure you used the right annotations? Otherwise the problem could be in the fact that you're using an Alpha build.

Comment: Make sure you're NOT using javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped.

Comment: I'm sure, I have posted it in the first line of my question post.

Comment: I think that the session CDI bean is not properly terminated

Comment: You need to make your user object null at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem probably comes from the fact that your producer doesn't have an explicit scope, so it has the `@Dependent`pseudo-scope. That means the producer code is called once at your EJB build-time and that the Injected value stays the same for all your EJB life.

You didn't mention how your `@Stateful` EJB is used, but I assume that it's injected in another piece of code so your code keep it longer than a request.

To correct your bug your should give a normal scope to your producer (`@RequestScoped`seems the best choice). So your producer code will become

```
@Produces @CurrentUser @RequestScoped
public User getUser() { ... }
```

Remember a producers doesn't inherit the scope from the bean that contains it.
With this normal scope, the `user` bean won't be directly injected, but CDI will inject a proxy of it. Thus the `currentUser` will stay the same only during the life of the current request.

Don't hesitate to read the [dependent scope chapter of the CDI 1.1 spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#dependent_context), it's quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

i have had similar issues before, i feel ur session pages are cached and you to clear them  by
   doing this

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");          // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

in your FilterServlet.